# Match a character in string and add characters before and after matched string using R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I have a list of random strings like `kzyFw4hw8EOC/655` and I want to match if the string has `/` character and if it does add a `"` character before and after the `/` like this:

```
Before = kzyFw4hw8EOC/655
After = kzyFw4hw8EOC"/"655
```

Comment: What have you tried and what about it didn't work?

Comment: Your code as-is won't run, because strings need quotes around them. From there, the tag is good: go read `?gsub`.

Comment: Do you need double quotes around your slash? If not, then single quote seem to work: gsub(pattern = "/", x = "kzyFw4hw8EOC/655", replacement = "'/'")

Comment: Thanks @TravisHinkelman. I figured out the same and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I modified the code to include the strings in single quotes. (R requires single or double quotes for strings. I used single quotes so as not to have to escape the double quotes.)

```
Before <- 'kzyFw4hw8EOC/655'
After <- 'kzyFw4hw8EOC"/"655'
```

Using base R:

```
gsub.method <- gsub('/', '"/"', Before)
gsub.method == After
# [1] TRUE
```

or using the package `stringr` from the `tidydverse`:

```
library(stringr)
stringr.method <- str_replace(Before, '/', '"/"')
stringr.method == After
# [1] TRUE
```